# Can't read two bytes through Serial.read - Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, android

I'm sending via Bluetooth with an Android App two bytes like this:

```
private void _sendCommand(byte command, byte arg)
{
    if (CONNECTED)
    {
        try
        {
            os.write(new byte[]{command, arg});
            os.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error sending command: " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code I'm using to receive them with Arduino:

```
byte _instruction;
byte _arg;

void loop() 
{    
  while(Serial.available() < 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }

  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  _instruction = Serial.read();
  _arg = Serial.read();
  Serial.flush();

  switch (_instruction) 
  {

     ...

  }
}
```

I don't have any problems sending just one byte (modifying the code to receive just one), but I can't do the same with two bytes. It's always stuck in the while. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

---

EDIT: As ST2000 pointed out, there was a problem of syncronization, so this is the code working properly:

```
void loop() 
{    
  // Wait until instruction byte has been received.
  while (!Serial.available());
  // Instruction should be read. MSB is set to 1
  _instruction = (short) Serial.read();

  if (_instruction & 0x80)
  {
    // Wait until arg byte has been received.
    while (!Serial.available());
    // Read the argument.
    _arg = (short) Serial.read();

    switch (_instruction) 
    {
      ...
    }
  }

  Serial.flush();
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What test data are you using? Try sending printable bytes (ASCII) first.

Comment: @MikaelPatel I'm sending as first byte 0x50 and as second byte a value between 0 and 100.

Comment: Your code never gets out of the while loop ?

Comment: @AndreCourchesne No, it does not.

Comment: How was your source code when sending succesfully only one byte ?

Comment: Have tried just with a serial port (not bluetooth), using the serial monitor if it works ? Maybe just maybe it's not the receiving end that does not work but rather the transmit side.

Comment: I suggest you always pull data in (for example use: "while(Serial.available() == 0);") then process what you expect to be the command and data bytes.  In your code there is nothing to recover from the receiver going out of synchronization with the transmitter.  For all you know, the transmitter has sent the command byte then the data byte.  However, the receiver may have skipped a byte and thinks the data byte is the command byte and is eternally waiting for what it thinks should be the data byte.  Which, of course, will never come.

Comment: @st2000 That makes sense, but, how do I recover if I'm out of sync?

Comment: By uniquely identifying commands as opposed to data.  Some protocols sacrifice a bit.  For example you could set the most significant bit for commands and not set the most significant bit for data.  However, that does mean you can only send data in the range of 0 to 127.  And it does restrict you to only 128 commands.  If you need more, and want to stick to this "most significant bit" approach, you could break your data into chunks and only send 7 bits at a time.  The possibilities are many.  Use this one or make one up that fits your needs better.

Comment: Let us know if this works & I'll copy these comments to the answer section.

Comment: @st2000 Thanks, a range of 0 to 127 will do, and 128 commands are more than enough. I'll give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: @st2000 Yes! It's working.

Comment: Thanks for following up.  This will make a good question / answer resource for anyone who is having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a underlying problem with synchronizing the transmitter and receiver.  They both have to agree / know which is a command byte and which is a data byte.

In order to do this, some protocols sacrifice a bit. For example you could set the most significant bit for commands and not set the most significant bit for data. However, that does mean you can only send data in the range of 0 to 127. And it does restrict you to only 128 commands. If you need more, and want to stick to this "most significant bit" approach, you could break your data into chunks and only send 7 bits at a time. The possibilities are many. Use this one or make one up that fits your needs better.

In order to implement this approach, you will need to read and process each byte as it arrives.  You can not wait until you accumulate the expected number of bytes as this assume you are always in sync with the transmitter. Which may not be the case.